# Use custom attribute with simple_form in a collection select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

In simple_form you can do a collection select this way:

```
= simple_form_for @document do |document|
  = f.input :name
  = f.input :type, collection: DocumentType.all, include_blank: false
```

This defaults to the DocumentTypes *:id*, and saves that in the document's *:type* attribute.

How do you tell simple_form which attribute of DocumentType to use?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the **value_method:** parameter.

```
= simple_form_for @document do |document|
  = f.input :name
  = f.input :type, collection: DocumentType.all, value_method: :name, include_blank: false
```

In this case it will use the DocumentType's *:name* attribute as *:type*.